# How Can I Convert datetime.timedelta to int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I wrote these codes for prediction and test accuracy on some dataset with the help of sklearn random forest classifier.

Code

```
a = datetime.datetime.now()
y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
b = datetime.datetime.now()

rf_time = b-a

rf_ac = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

print(type(rf_time))
print('Random Forest Time Duration - ',b-a)
print("Random Forest Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Output

```
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
Random Forest Time Duration -  0:00:00.011969
Random Forest Accuracy: 0.6324761904761905
```

Here I got the `rf_time` which type is `datetime.timedelta`. Now, How can I convert this `datetime.timedelta` into integer. How can I get the int value from the `0:00:00.011969`?

Comment: What is the int unit ? ns, µs, ms, days ?

Comment: int unit can be ns us or ms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generic form to get timedelta in `UNIT` is:

```py
delta / timedelta(UNIT=1)
```

with `UNIT` one of `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`, `microseconds`, `milliseconds`.

**NB.** this is a division, which in python always gives a float, so you might need to convert/display as `int` manually.

For seconds, there is [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds).

Example:

```py
timedelta(days=1) / timedelta(hours=1)  # gives 24.0
```

---

For the above question, OP can use this `print` statement for timedelta as a number in µs.

```py
print(
    'Random Forest Time Duration (in µs) -',
    rf_time / datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1)
)
```

Comment: can show me the implementation with my given code?

Comment: `rf_time / datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1)` for instance for microseconds

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what unit you want you interger to be:
for seconds you could use:

```
from datetime import timedelta
rf_time = timedelta(hours=1)
t_integer = int(t.total_seconds())
t_integer
```

output:
[image]

[image]

if you want ns you can use:

```
t_integer = int(t.total_seconds() * 1e9)
```

output:
[image]

for us you can use `* 1e6` etc

Comment: images aren't loading properly.

Comment: hmm that is weird, also not if you click on them? they are standard stackoverflow, hosted on imgur..